# Binded property not refreshing while event called from another User Control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

To simplify situation. I have MainWindow with two user controls, all of them have corresponding Viewmodels. Everything works fine, properties bind and so on, beside one functionality.

I want to refresh data on second user control after event happened in the first one. Unfortunetly in this scenario, PropertyChanged event (derived from INotifyPropertyChanged, defined in ViewModelBase) is null.

However, if I raise an event from second user control, property on view gets updated as expected!

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
      public FirstUserControl FirstUserControl {get; set;}
      public SecondUserControl SecondUserControl {get; set;}

      public MainWindowViewModel ()
      {
             FirstUserControl =new FirstUserControl();
             FirstUserControl.RaiseClicked+=OnRaiseClicked;

             SecondUserControl = new SecondUserControl();
             SecondUserControl .RaiseClicked+=OnRaiseClicked;
      }

      private void OnRaiseClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            SecondUserControl.RefreshView();
      }
}



public class FirstUserControl : ViewModelBase
{
      public ICommand Raise { get; private set; }

      public EventHandler RaiseClicked {get;set;}

      public FirstUserControl ()
      {
             Raise = new RelayCommand( p=> RaiseClicked(this, null));
      }
}

public class SecondUserControl: ViewModelBase
{
      public ICommand Raise { get; private set; }

      public EventHandler RaiseClicked {get;set;}

      public string Title
      {  
           get
           {
                return MyLogic.GetCurrentTitle(); // debuggers enter here only while event on second user control raised
           }
      }

      public void  RefreshView()
      { 
            OnPropertyChanged("Title"); // debugger enter here in cases
      }
}
```

I suppose there is something with threads going on, but I'm not that familiar with WPF to work out it by my own. Can someone help how to quickly and easy make event from first UC refresh data on the second?

Comment: I think seeing your xaml would help.  I'm prematurely guessing that the datacontext of the FirstUserControl that is clicked in the UI may not be the viewmodel instance from your MainViewModel.

Comment: @MarkW You can assume everything on that side is correct. I've simplified the code for question purposes, there are many other properties and command in my project and all of them are working correctly

Comment: I used your code (with my own BasicViewModel and ButtonCommand) and it works fine. You need to supply more code like Mark W said if you still need help